# How to make Wordpress Short-code for recent posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a simple Wordpress shortcode for recent posts to use it inside a post.

I know the basic steps of creating a shortcode:

1- I open the WP theme "functions.php" file and include a new custom file created in same directory i name it "custom-shortcode.php"

2- Inside the "custom-shortcode.php" i write the actual code:

```
 <?php

     // Shortcode function
    function custom_shortcode() {

        // Use WP recent posts function with default values return
        return php wp_get_recent_posts( $args, $output );
    }
    // Add shortcode (WP function)
    add_shortcode( 'recent-post', 'custom_shortcode' );


?>
```

I want to use the wp default function for getting recent posts, is my code will work?
I want to get shortcode with minimal code and with default values return so i can focus on learning how can i make my own shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`shortcode_atts(array(` for make your custom style..

You can follow , http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API